# Are the Robinsons in the first batch of humans to settle Alpha Centauri?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-2018

I got into a debate over whether the folks on the *Resolute* are the first batch of colonists headed to Alpha Centauri.

I say they're not the first batch because:

- The promotional video seems to depict life at the colony.
- They're called the 24th Colonist Group.
- One of the kids asks Don West what Alpha Centauri is like, since he's been there three times.

The other party says they are the first because:

- Maureen is working on the design of the Jupiters and the *Resolute* right up until they go.

  > * It's implied that the speed of the *Resolute* is due to stolen alien engine technology from the "Christmas star" that happens just a year or two before their departure.

Have I missed something definitive?

Comment: IDK about the other two, but I think the middle point means they were number 24 on the Resolute, that's all.

Comment: There are several references to the fact that there are already people on Alpha Centauri, most notably several conversations with Don West about his previous trips there and back.

Comment: I'm not sure the other guy's point makes sense - so this was the first *fast* ship, why does that mean there weren't earlier *slow* ships?

Comment: @HarryJohnston:  I think the underlying assumption is that it wasn't actually feasible to get to Alpha Centauri in a slow ship.  It would have to have been a generation ship or a sleeper ship.

Comment: Doesn't the Don West thing disprove that assumption outright?  It might or might not make *sense* that people could or would travel back and forth in slower ships, but when it comes down to it, you can't necessarily expect a movie to make sense.  [NB: this is not intended as a criticism of the question, which is perfectly sound.  I'd probably post an answer if I'd actually ever seen the movie!]

Comment: @HarryJohnston the lost-in-space-2018 tags suggests the question is about the 2018 Netflix show, not the 2000 Matt LeBlanc movie.

Comment: @Jontia, oh, I thought it was another movie.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy having finally got to the end, I can see why the truncated timeline is causing people issues. I reckon they have to be running the colony missions at a minimum of once a month to fit your spoiler text in with the Mission number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out in the question, the Robinsons are in the 24th colonist group. There are numerous instances where the show implies or outright states that others have gone before them.

- Episode 1: Before the crash sequence, Maureen tells them not to worry because The Resolute has done this 23 times before.
- Episode 1: The "24" patch does not refer to their number within this colonisation group. That would be "2", their ship is the Jupiter 2.
- Episode 4: Don is smuggling Whiskey to someone. It could be on spec to the current wave of colonists, I suppose.
- Episode 5: Penny asks if they will get "one of those sweet family units in town".
- Episode 6: Angela's husband is referred to a the 7th musician selected for colonisation, sending 7 in the first wave would be a large burden on the small colony. Assuming they lack other technical skill sets.
- Episode 7: Evan tells Judy that his brother is already at the colony with his "horrible wife".

While the above makes it clear this is mission 24, the Episode 9 revelation;

> The "Christmas Star" was a crashed alien space ship, who's engine is incorporated into the *Resolute*. Means they appear to be running one or two colony missions a month, based on the lack of the Robinson children (Will especially) visibly ageing between the flashback to the news report and their departure for the colony.